# По какой причине может не работать RDP на windows server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows, rdp, windows-server-2008-r2

Как переустанавливаю дедик, спустя несколько дней **постоянно** и **неожиданно** пропадает возможность подключиться к серверу через удаленный рабочий стол. Ошибка стандартная - типа "удаленный компьютер выключен".
Хотя через сторонний софт удаленного подключения все работает нормально в это время.

Переустанавливаю систему - через несколько дней опять то же самое начинается. Хотя по началу удаленный рабочий стол подключается нормально. 
В чем может быть проблема в моем случае?

Comment: А служба запущена? А порт открыт?

Answer (score 1):

диспетчер лицензирования работает ?
тут что у тебя установлено ?

[image: RDP1]

логи бы глянуть - что там про RDP пишут

[image: RDP2]